# Invalid query: Not unique table/alias: 'st'

Tags: php, mysql

Can you please help me out to my query. I check my previous query table it works but this can't worked.

```
                SELECT cj.customer_jd,
                customertable.name,
                customertable.ordersize,
                cj.job_no,
                cj.id,
                cj.ordered_quantity, 
                cj.ordered_quantity,st.id AS sandingID,
                st.*
                FROM sandingtable AS st
                LEFT JOIN customer_job  AS cj  ON 
                customertable.id=cj.customer_jd
                RIGHT JOIN  st ON cj.id = st.`job_id`
               WHERE st.date= '$date' AND st.shift = '$shift' AND 
                st.sandingno=".$row['sandingno']."");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `customer_table` in the `from` clause:

```
FROM sandingtable st LEFT JOIN
     customer_job cj 
     ON customertable.id = cj.customer_jd RIGHT JOIN
     st
     ON cj.id = st.`job_id`
WHERE st.date = '$date' AND st.shift = '$shift' AND 
      st.sandingno = ".$row['sandingno']."");
```

I'm not sure exactly how to fix it, but maybe something like this:

```
from st left join
     customer_job cj 
     on cj.id = st.job_id left join
     customertable 
     on customertable.id = cj.customer_jd
. . .
```

Notes:

- I would use the alias `ct` for `customertable`, but the rest of the query uses `customertable`.
- You should use `left join`s consistently in a query.  Mixing left and right joins is just confusing.